# Using tidyverse to dynamically mutate one variable from one grouped dataset from another dataset

Tags: r, loops, iteration, tidyverse, dplyr

Let's say I work with different classes (nodes, in my dataset) and I have thousands of students. Each student has their own math score, and I need to compare all individual scores with the group mean/sd.
To deal with that, I have two different datasets. The first one is "a table".
[image: default table]

This data frame is formed of several classes (nodes), their means, and their sd.

I also have another dataset composed of students' results, like this one:

[image: students' results]

I want to have another dataset in which I get all individual results (i.e., 11, 6, 10, etc) and subtract this result from all means in the first dataset. In the future, it will be needed to check all results and all nodes together.

In other words, from the first nome (number 12 in the image), I will subtract 11 (student's result) from 68 (mean result), 6 (student's result) from 68 (mean), 10 (student's result) from 68 (mean), etc.
Then I'll move for the second node (number 7 in the image), and I will do the same (subtract 11 from 74 (mean result), 6 from 74 (mean result), 10 from 74),

The final output I would like to have is below. Please, take this image as illustrative-only:
[image: Final output]

Due to questions, to make my question clear, the following command also brings an interesting solution, but it's not functional since I'll have to manually add all columns to the new dataset:

```
test_result %>% 
  mutate(total_header_node_12 = x - default_table$t_mean[1]) %>% 
  mutate(total_header_node_74 = x - default_table$t_mean[2])
```

[image: Another desired output]

I searched for other questions but I did not find any solution.
Any help is valuable. I use tidyverse, and I would like to remain within tidyverse environment.
Thank you
**To reproduce:**

```
> dput(default_table)
structure(list(node = structure(c(6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("4", 
"5", "7", "8", "10", "12", "13"), class = "factor"), t_mean = c(68.8219178082192, 
74.3260869565217, 83.0178571428571, 92.2108108108108, 98.3304347826087, 
88.6111111111111, 48.4), t_sd = c(14.4351088961341, 16.9448394654941, 
13.0272663858681, 12.2011483603603, 12.1775472144027, 14.5621088567959, 
10.4876948807826), vars = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), n = c(121, 
74, 92, 616, 191, 58, 7), mean = c(68, 74.6891891891892, 82.8369565217391, 
91.3944805194805, 97.738219895288, 88.0172413793103, 48.7142857142857
), sd = c(14.0226008048911, 16.1151045250761, 11.0426517498479, 
12.6758935948866, 12.0212336250146, 15.9169901273025, 8.63547500554709
), min = c(32, 32, 58, 36, 56, 44, 39), max = c(97, 113, 104, 
123, 128, 124, 60), range = c(65, 81, 46, 87, 72, 80, 21), se = c(1.27478189135374, 
1.87334284914993, 1.15127602962793, 0.510726307415094, 0.869825937534791, 
2.09000319547951, 3.26390275965596), q0_25 = c(59, 64, 74.75, 
84, 90, 80, 41.5), q0_5 = c(68, 73.5, 81.5, 92, 98, 87, 47), 
    q0_75 = c(80, 87.75, 92.25, 100, 106, 98.75, 56)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))


test_result <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100,10,2))
```

Comment: Do the numbers in screenshots from R and excel match?

Comment: No, excel is just a preview of what I want. No relationship at all.

Comment: @CalumYou, Actually, I don't have this variable there. I can suppress this information and just have the values. Thanks

Comment: So student result in excel matches with `test_result$x` in R?

Comment: This image in excel is illustrative only. In this case, it matches, but it's just to show the desired output. I'll edit the question to make my ask clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

default_table %>%
  tidyr::crossing(test_result) %>%
  mutate(comparative_mean = x - t_mean)
```

This creates all combinations of `default_table` with `test_result` and then we subtract the two values from each other.

Comment: I'm impressed! I did not know this function from tidyverse!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the student results as a new column and then `unnest` to get a long form data that you can do this comparison on. There is probably also a solution with `crossing` but this seemed simpler. Essentially, we want to insert the student results as a new column in the `default_table`, and then use `unnest` to expand so there is one row per node-student, as in the desired output. Then we can simply subtract the mean from the student results.

```r
set.seed(1)
library(tidyverse)
default_table <- structure(list(node = structure(c(6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("4", "5", "7", "8", "10", "12", "13"), class = "factor"), t_mean = c(68.8219178082192, 74.3260869565217, 83.0178571428571, 92.2108108108108, 98.3304347826087, 88.6111111111111, 48.4), t_sd = c(14.4351088961341, 16.9448394654941, 13.0272663858681, 12.2011483603603, 12.1775472144027, 14.5621088567959, 10.4876948807826), vars = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), n = c(121, 74, 92, 616, 191, 58, 7), mean = c(68, 74.6891891891892, 82.8369565217391, 91.3944805194805, 97.738219895288, 88.0172413793103, 48.7142857142857), sd = c(14.0226008048911, 16.1151045250761, 11.0426517498479, 12.6758935948866, 12.0212336250146, 15.9169901273025, 8.63547500554709), min = c(32, 32, 58, 36, 56, 44, 39), max = c(97, 113, 104, 123, 128, 124, 60), range = c(65, 81, 46, 87, 72, 80, 21), se = c(1.27478189135374, 1.87334284914993, 1.15127602962793, 0.510726307415094, 0.869825937534791, 2.09000319547951, 3.26390275965596), q0_25 = c(59, 64, 74.75, 84, 90, 80, 41.5), q0_5 = c(68, 73.5, 81.5, 92, 98, 87, 47), q0_75 = c(80, 87.75, 92.25, 100, 106, 98.75, 56)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
test_result <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10,10,2))

test_result <- test_result %>%
  rowid_to_column(var = "student_number") %>%
  rename(student_result = x)

default_table %>%
  mutate(students = map(node, ~ test_result)) %>%
  unnest(students) %>%
  mutate(comparative_mean = student_result - mean) %>%
  select(node, mean, student_number, student_result, comparative_mean)
#> # A tibble: 70 x 5
#>    node   mean student_number student_result comparative_mean
#>    <fct> <dbl>          <int>          <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1 12       68              1           8.75            -59.3
#>  2 12       68              2          10.4             -57.6
#>  3 12       68              3           8.33            -59.7
#>  4 12       68              4          13.2             -54.8
#>  5 12       68              5          10.7             -57.3
#>  6 12       68              6           8.36            -59.6
#>  7 12       68              7          11.0             -57.0
#>  8 12       68              8          11.5             -56.5
#>  9 12       68              9          11.2             -56.8
#> 10 12       68             10           9.39            -58.6
#> # … with 60 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Could you please explain (or link for a tutorial) the mutate(students = map(node, ~ test_result)) %>%  unnest(students)  part. When I create "students" (via mutate and then map), what R is doing behind the scene? Your solution is pretty much elegant.

Comment: `map` applies a function to a vector and returns a list of the same length. Here I just pick `node` and use the compact function syntax `~ test_result`, which is equivalent to `function() {test_result}`, i.e. it just returns the test_result table no matter the input.